# Drawable não está pegando imagens

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Galera, estou fazendo um app que tem um drawer, e o menu que aparece lateralmente é uma navigationView. Até ai tudo bem, mas no código .xml que quero adicionar ícones, não está pegando as imagens.

O código .xml do drawer está assim:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Home" />
```

Mas dentro da pasta drawable o objeto ic_menu_camera não é uma imagem e sim outro código .xml. Assim:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2H9zm3,15c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z"/>
```

Gostaria de trocar esse icone mas quando adiciono uma imagem .png na pasta drawable e chamo assim(código abaixo), não aparece a imagem:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:title="Home" />
```

Comment: ola, gostaria de saber se vc conseguiu resolver esse problema , pois estou com o mesmo e preciso de ajuda , obrigado!